# How to pass parameters for dependency while Injecting services in services in Angular 2 ( Ionic 2 / Angular 2 / Typescript )

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2, angular2-services

I'm making a sample application to make connection to a websocket server in ionic 2 in typescript. link to [repo](https://github.com/mehdhi/ionic2websocketconnectionsample)

My requirement is to make the websocket connection during application start up

I'm using [angular2-websocket](https://github.com/afrad/angular2-websocket) to creating the connection.

References :

1. http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html
2. http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html

I'm getting a error " Cannot resolve all parameters for '$WebSocket'(String, Array, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that '$WebSocket' is decorated with Injectable. "

CODE:
[app.ts](https://github.com/mehdhi/ionic2websocketconnectionsample/blob/master/app/app.ts)

```
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';
import {ConnectionService} from './framework/connection/connection-service'
import {$WebSocket} from 'angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

// https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Type-interface.html
import {Type} from 'angular2/core';


@App({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  config: {}
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: Type = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, private conn : ConnectionService) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.conn.connect();
    });
  }
}
bootstrap(MyApp, [$WebSocket, ConnectionService]);
```

[connection-service.ts](https://github.com/mehdhi/ionic2websocketconnectionsample/blob/master/app/framework/connection/connection-service.ts)

```
import {Injectable, Component, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {$WebSocket} from 'angular2-websocket/angular2-websocket';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Injectable()
export class ConnectionService {

    private _status: number;

    //private connection: $WebSocket;

    constructor( private connection : $WebSocket = new $WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org") ) {

    console.log("Starting connection");

   //this.connection = new $WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");

    this.connection.onClose(this.onCloseHandler);
    this.connection.onError(this.onErrorHandler);
    this.connection.onOpen(this.onOpenHandler);
    this.connection.onMessage(this.onRecieveHandler, {});

}
...
public connect() {
    this.connection.connect(true);
}
...
}
bootstrap(ConnectionService, [$WebSocket]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Solution to my problem was using @App() Annotation's (Specific to ionic) provider field instead of using bootstrap

```
bootstrap(ConnectionService, 
    [provide($WebSocket, useValue: new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org")]);
```

Eg.

```
@App({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  config: {},
  providers : [ provide( $WebSocket, { useValue: new $WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org") }), ConnectionService]
})
```

Working sample can be found [here](https://github.com/mehdhi/ionic2websocketconnectionsample)

Comment: `@App()` is an Ionic specific annotation?

Comment: @Gunter yes its specific to Ionic. Can be imported from 'ionic-framework/ionic';

Comment: This means that you don't need to bootstrap in Ionic2 apps @tymSpy?

Comment: App is an Ionic decorator that bootstraps an application. It can be passed a number of arguments that act as global config variables for the app. `@App` is similar to Angular's `@Component` in which it can accept a `template` property that has an inline template, or a `templateUrl` property that points to an external html template.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the `$WebSocket` requires a `string`, `array` and another parameter which makes `$WebSocket` not injectable, at least not directly.

As a workaround you can use

```
import {Injectable, Component, Inject, provide} from 'angular2/core';

bootstrap(ConnectionService, 
    [provide( $WebSocket, { useValue: new $WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org") })]);
```

There are other options if the string literal is not what you want, like a factory.

Comment: @tymspy, thanks for fixing! I'm only using Dart myself and often forget about the syntax differences.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you should provide `$WebSocket` by injection since you instantiate it by your own for your service. I would remove it from `bootstrap` and instantiate it in the constructor instead of providing it from constructor parameters:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConnectionService {
  private _status: number;
  private connection: $WebSocket;

  constructor() {
    this.connection = new $WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");
  }
}
```

That said, in general, if you want to leverage dependency injection in Angular, you must **let Angular2 instantiate by itself** things you want to inject in the constructor.

In your case, Angular2 tries to instantiate your `$WebSocket` service. I think that its constructor accepts three parameters and when Angular2 tries to resolve these parameters at instantiation level. It can't resolve the last one. Could you provide the parameters of the `$WebService` constructor?

Comment: url:string, protocols?:Array<string>, config?: WebSocketConfig. The last two are optional.

Comment: In fact the `WebSocketConfig` is something that Angular2 can't resolve. If you want to use `$WebSocket` with dependency injection, you need to set a provider for it: `provide(WebSocketConfig, useValue: new WebSocketConfig(...)` but I think that you will have problems with string parameters...

Comment: Thanks for tip. I used the App decorators annotation's providers instead of  bootstrap with provide($WebSocket, useValue: new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org") solved my problem