# Dependancy Injection in Angular 2 - Ionic2 & typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm having some issues with bootstrapping some files in my app. Building on top of the Ionic2 tabs example.

I have a Service and a User file, each decorated with @injectable. I want 1 instance across the whole app, so i am trying to bootstrap it. I have added Platform to the providers, i'm not sure if i need 1 instance for the whole app, or per component?

```
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';
import {User} from './User.ts';
import {Service} from './Service.ts';
import {Type} from 'angular2/core';

@App({
    template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
    providers: [Platform]
})
export class MyApp {

    rootPage: Type = TabsPage;

    constructor(platform: Platform, user: User) {

        platform.ready().then(() => {
            user.start();
        });

    }
}

bootstrap(MyApp, [
    Service,
    User 
]);
```

I get 2 errors in the console

> Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Platform'(?). Make sure that all
>   the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type
>   annotations and that 'Platform' is decorated with Injectable.

and then

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined

My service for example, looks like this

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class Service {
   //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to pass parameters for dependency while Injecting services in services in Angular 2 ( Ionic 2 / Angular 2 / Typescript )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718249/how-to-pass-parameters-for-dependency-while-injecting-services-in-services-in-an?rq=1)

This post suggests that @App is an ionic decorator that bootstraps the app. I added User and Service to the providers and all seems to be functioning. Platform need not be added to the providers.

```
@App({
    template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
    providers: [User, Service]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify `Platform` into providers of your component:

```
@App({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
  providers: [Platform] // <------
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage: Type = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, user: User) {
    (...)
  }
}
```

Moreover I don't think that you need the `.ts` extension into your imports:

```
//import {User} from './User.ts';
//import {Service} from './Service.ts';
import {User} from './User';
import {Service} from './Service';
```

Do you TypeScript or ES6 into your project?

Comment: Typescript throughout. I've now removed platform from providers, and added User and Service to it, rather than bootstrapping them